# Asp.net 2.0 solution getting hundreds of HttpRequestValidationException from other sites not my own

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

Ive got an interesting issue happening.The site is getting a bunch of the error messages from other sites (not my own):

```
 Exception type: HttpRequestValidationException 
 Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (comment="...er[/url]  <a href="http://obey..."). 
 Request path: /404_custom.aspx
```

The source host is not my server IP and the URL is from a completely different URL however it is ending up in my Event Viewer. Im assuming this is some kind of spambot that is causing issues - or potentially i have stumbled upon a problem with my IIS application.

We have the following in our web.config:

```
<httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404_custom.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I understand that these errors are caused by corss-site scripting, but why would the host of the site be another site thats not my own? Could it do with the bindings set against the IIS application?

Does anyone know of why this would be happening? Is this caused by a spambot or some sort of attack? Anyone have any words of widsom?

Comment: This is simply some kind of bot that probes your web server for open security holes. I don't think that it is a attack directed explicitly against you. It more likely is a simple bot that works like a spider: It goes from URL to URL and attacks each server it encounters.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth why would it be showing up with the host thats not our website address or IPs?

Comment: Doing a bunch of reading on the net - it says it could be referer spam I am seeing. Does this help?